# Django Authentication Application

Tags: django

I've just started to the django and got a little lost in between various doumentations and outdated tutorials.

What I want to achieve is to create a simple dashboard application that also contains some backend scripts to integrate various apis most of them are open API's like weather API's , calendar API's etc just for learning.

But I need to create a login page for the application and current tutorials for the authentication mosule of django is a little bit cunfusing as it never gives me how to implemelent a login form to the auth backend. I need a little bir more simple documentation for that.

Is there anyone able to help me on that. I know the question is not code related but still any help will be appriceated. Most of findings from my previous searches are outdated and implementing those methods are often causes errors like non-existent templates etc...

Meanwhile I'll be also checking the offical documentation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it depends what view you use to handle login as there are two types of views Class based and function based. I use Function based so I shall explain you with that.

First you should set up an html page that will have the form to take the details of the username and password. I assume you know how to do that and how to handle the form in the html (if not please comment is shall explain you that too). So now the view that will handle the login authentication is below

```
from django.contrib.auth import login,authenticate

def login_page(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
        username =  request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username= username, password= password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('any_page_you_want_to_send_the_user')
   else:
       return render(request, 'login.html')
```

So what the above code does is that it accepts a POST request that you send from your login form and then it **gets** the username and password from that form. Then it uses the django's **authenticate** function to authenticate the user. It then checks if the there is actually an user or it is None(doesn't exists). And if the condition is true, it logs in the current user.

Comment: Yes I know how to create a simple html form for that and I also know that I gonna need to put a csrf token on it. But let me try this first. 

I presume we will take this as a base level and built the session handling on top of it am I right?

Comment: Yes this is the minimum code to log in a user. You can add complexity now according to you requirements.

Comment: what I can't see and probably underestand is you don't render any html pages here. How django will know which html file to use as a login form

Comment: oh I am sorry I missed that part I shall add that code, So if there is no POST request it will render out the login.html (which is a GET method)

Comment: That works but now it immediately redirects the page to some non-existing endpoint. /accounts/login/netx=/ which is of course does not exist yet. Also I need to figure it out to hide password somehow in the future.

Comment: You can control the redirection by specifying the url of your choice

Comment: Nope it was all my bad the form action was wrong. But wonder how can I point the form action to the right place. 

Why django documentation is so confusing in this area especially. Even tutorial doesn't mention a single thing about authentication and session handling.

Comment: By the way my friend thank you for your. help. Now I have a simple little boilerplate that checks if the user exists and if not returns to the login screent again. 

Things will go on from now on so I'll mark this one answered:)